# Removing duplicated observations in r with restriction

Tags: r

I have a dataset with which contains duplicates of the ident variable.
I need to select only 1 observation of each ident and it needs to be the newest value, i.e. the resulting data should contain the observation for the ident where the 'year' is the highest in the initial data set.

I believe a general case would look like this:

```
1. ident   value   year
 2. A       1       19X1
 3. A       2       19X2
 4. B       4       19X2
 5. B       2       19X1
 6. B       1       19X3
 7. C       1       19X4
 8. C       2       19X1
```

(I could not order it in a proper table here, so please disregard the numbered list on the left)

Only, I have several hundred thousands obs.

Order of the resulting data set is not important to me.

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Comment: Try `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, .SD[which.max(year)], ident]` or `setDT(df1)[order(-year),  head(.SD, 1), ident]`

Comment: Is the year in the same form as mentioned in the question? Or is it an integer like 1998, 1996 etc?

Comment: Heroka: I tried some code using `table(df)` and merge the resulting freq var to df. this cannot help my to define that i want to keep the observation of a given year.

Kunal Puri: the year is in integer form yes and takes values of [1986:2014].
(i just stated it as above to be general as it should work for both 80's and 90's as well with 2000's)

Answer (score 1):

Using library `dplyr` you can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ident) %>% arrange(desc(year)) %>% slice(1)
```

Output will be as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: ident [3]

    X1. ident value  year
  (dbl) (chr) (int) (chr)
1     3     A     2  19X2
2     6     B     1  19X3
3     7     C     1  19X4
```

This assumes `year` is in a format where sorting in descending order makes it go from latest to oldest.

NOTE: that x1. column is a result of your input data above. I just read it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$ident), 
                            function(x) x[which.max(x$year), ]))
```